# Running jQuery Code Each time I click on a button

Tags: jquery

How do I run the below jQuery code every time I click on the next button on the page? Next button is under ".next" class

```
$(".name").each(function(){
    if (($(this).text()) != "apple"){
        $(this).closest(".list").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works, thank you everyone!!

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
    $(".name").each(function(){
        if (($(this).text()) != "Xyz"){
            $(this).closest(".list").hide();
        }
    });}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by under the .next class but typically you can have jQuery run code using the [click event listener](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
$("#id_of_element").click(function(){
    alert("button clicked");
}
```

Comment: So every time I click the button (.next), I want jQuery to perform the jQuery code at the top. Now I wrapped that jQuery with .click function it doesnt work

Comment: It says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: $(".next").click(function(){ $(".name").each(function(){ if (($(this).text()) != "Squad Fitness"){ $(this).closest(".listFUTItem").hide(); } }); });

Comment: above code does the job, the only problem is that, It performs the job under the click function before the new list gets loaded. So I am trying to hide all non-squad fitness items, it is hiding them then loading next page right away, then I click next it hides those fields first then loads next page not letting me see non-hidden items if I make sense...

Comment: Each time I click .next button, page is made by someone else, page loads all new list of products. I want to hide all products that I am not interested in with this code. What it is doing is that, it's hiding them then loading next bunch of products right away each time I click.

Answer (score 0):

1- you need to put your code inside a document.ready function

2- give that button an id like this `<button id=btn...`

3- put this script code right before the end of the body tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function() {
      if (($('.name').text()) != "apple"){
    $('.name').closest(".list").hide();
     }
});
});
```

4- You need to wait for the elements to be available the dom on page load before binding event handlers
5- make sure this nex button click event is not already firing with another script/code.

Comment: $(".next").click(function(){
 $(".name").each(function(){
  if (($(this).text()) != "Squad Fitness"){
   $(this).closest(".listFUTItem").hide();
  }
 });
});

Comment: above code does the job, the only problem is that, It performs the job under the click function before the new list gets loaded. So I am trying to hide all non-squad fitness items, it is hiding them then loading next page right away, then I click next it hides those fields first then loads next page not letting me see non-hidden items if I make sense...

Comment: Each time I click .next button, page is made by someone else, page loads all new list of products. I want to hide all products that I am not interested in with this code. What it is doing is that, it's hiding them then loading next bunch of products right away each time I click.

Comment: you can use ajaxComplete() instead if its loading by ajax

Comment: use this $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {